# Objective-C midpoint between two times

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, nsdate, nscalendar

I have two NSDates formatted as "h:mm a" as time, (i.e. 6:00 AM and 8:00 PM).

I am trying to find out what time is the midpoint between those two times.

For the example above, the midpoint between 6:00 AM and 8:00 PM would be 1:00 PM.

But I do not know how to do this in objective-C for the iPhone sdk.

Any help or suggestions or code would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Perhaps something like the following is what you're after?

```
// Assuming you have two NSDate instances: start and end.
NSTimeInterval difference = [end timeIntervalSinceDate:start];
NSDate *middle = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:difference / 2 sinceDate:start];
```

See the [NSDate Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the times to a time interval, average the two numbers, then convert it back to an NSDate object.

Assuming your two times are instances of NSDate, that might look like this:

```
NSTimeInterval intA = [timeA timeIntervalSince1970];
NSTimeInterval intB = [timeB timeIntervalSince1970];

NSDate *avgTime = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:(intA + intB) / 2.0];
```